# Clock recovery for differential manchester code on an FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga, decoding, recovery

In am using an FPGA und have implemented a differential manchester decoder but right now, I am facing some problem with the clock recovery.

The background is that the clock of the manchester code is 40 MHz while I can only achieve an oversampling of 5. Thus, my clock inside the FPGA is 200 MHz.
Due to some distortions, the data stream is sometimes disturbed with some additional peak. Until now, I updated my recovered clock every directly by the incoming data stream.

But as some peaks are present the clock recovery fails. I do not have the possibility of using some training sequence for clock recovery.
Is there a best practice or even an implementation for clock recovery without an PLL for such a case?

**Clarification:**

The signal being fed into the FPGA is from a very fast comparator (about 4ns rise-time). The comparator distinguishes whether the signal is greater or equal to zero with some small hysteresis. The hysteresis is very small but can not be augmented.

I modified the wikipedia image to visualize the peak.
[image]

Comment: Very unclear what "peaks" you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with PLL circuity inside the FPGA. You can check out one [documentation](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/spartan-3a.htm) , hopefully this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to clean up your analog signal by proper termination, that could alleviate the peaks on your analog signal.

But you should also have a look at loop dynamics. Your design is unclear to me, but you cannot just adjust your recovered clock directly to any incoming edge. You need a loop, with it's dynamics, to take every incoming change, to slightly improve the reconstructed clock to finally reach a steady state.

Additionally did you consider clocking on the falling edge of your clock. I have no idea of what technology you are targetting, but if it supports both edges, you could have 10x oversampling.

Kind regards

Comment: My target platform is an Altera Max 10 FPGA. In the past I only used Xilinx, thus I don't know whether it supports both edges ... I have a take a look into the data sheet.